# CKEditor fixed textarea range

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

is it possible to set the textarea of CKEditor (the area in which you can write) to a fixed height and width? Our problem is, that we want to restrict this area to a fixed range of lines so that you can´t write more the e.g. 10 lines or not more than 600px.

Greetings from Austria

Comment: You have several options. One is CSS max-width and max-height, another is javascript events using onkeyup="countCharacters(this)". Ofc you should also have input verification afterwards on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following resources:

- ["Setting Editor Size" sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/size.html)
- ["Setting Editor Size" documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_size)

You can use the available configuration options such as [`config.width`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-width) and [`config.height`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-height) to set the editor width and height. After these values are reached, scrollbars will appear in your editor. Example:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        width: 600,
        height: 600
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i do not want to set the size of the whole editor, I just want to give the area, in which the text is written a fixed size or range, so that you can only write 10 lines and then pressing "enter" won´t be possible anymore.